sepolia faucet needed for my master thesis
anyone be kind to help me with 1 sepolia faucet for me finishing my master thesis project? thank you a lot
account:
0x6D10c5e67aDe3bc4ADDAeF07305f4EB8F33F026B

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x9a71463e22cc1ccd04d7899d9e9397a46ada310f21ce1addb516bdfcabb96759
